# get apache to serve a static file named index.html?parameter=1

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, static

I am working on a website on a low memory server. I edit/update the website in a CMS and then do a nighly wget to an other folder/vhost that serves fast static pages to the users.

It works great and fast, but now I found out that I have some pages that don't work.

Wget downloads index.php?id=10 and creates the file index.html?id=10.html

One specific folder of my website has the files index.html, index.html?id=1, index.html?id=2, index.html?id=3 etc

When i open www.mysite.com/myfolder/index.html?id=1.html in my browser i get index.html, even if the file index.html?id=1.html exists.

Does anybody have any solution for how to fix this? maybe an htaccess solution or something else?

I am looking forward to any ideas,

Comment: Is `index.html` a script (or contains some scripts) that can read and interpret the query string parameters like `id=1`?

Comment: Hi Anubhava, It is plain static html. no script. I have been thinking of fixing this with javascript, but that would not be very good for SEO. Do you have any sugestions?

Comment: @user2756794 I would start by fixing your php file to properly save the files with the right names, then making a script that rename all those files with wrong naming schema to their actual names for example `index.html?id=1.html` to `1.html` and then you can easily make a rule to redirect to those files permanently so you will have no further problems with it and your indexed pages will move along to the correct files.